# Shade sail/fabric covering with sealed/flush edges?

Tags: patio, pergola

I know the typical shade sail shape is bowed on the edges because of tension, etc. but is it possible to get a completely square shade sail? And also to have that shade sail be completely sealed/flushed on two edges against a structure?

There are already places to attach the shade sail/fabric solution.

From the picture below, I would like it flush/sealed against side A and B, and then angled down from A to C. All corners have a place to attach the sail/fabric.

[image]

Is there any solution that I can implement in this area?

Comment: You’ll need to contact a company that sews custom awnings, I see no reason they can’t make and install that for you.  It’s not the type of shade sail you can buy off amazon for $30-40 tho...

Comment: Do you want all the water to drain to side C? Why do you want to use a sail rather than a rigid surface? Do you want it to be translucent?

Comment: @JimStewart There seems to be a skylight above already. Perhaps it’s a visual barrier from top level to lower level. If it needs to be a temporary installation, it could be a friction fit... I’d hate to try and fasten into those walls. (Nice doors: two pair hinges.) Where is this...high wind area?

Comment: @Lee Sam, didn't think about that, but prolly is fine screen that admits rain.